# When I rotate my legs using the assigned bone, it weirdly makes the legs thiner, any solutions?

Tags: animation, armature, bones

For some reason when I rotate part of an object it makes the legs thiner

*Without rotation*

[image]

*With rotation*

[image]

Anyone know how to fix this issue?
I have parented the object to the bones with *empty groups*

Comment: Looking  at your images, it seems some sort of "robotic" spider, so it could also be made of separate arms sections, and in this way moving the lower section would not impact the upper at all... just an idea. Instead, if you need an "organic" spider, you have to follow @Mentalist answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's because the topology of your legs doesn't have enough geometry, so it doesn't deform well.

Look at some examples comparing good and bad joint topology. (The good ones have a denser, "capped" extrusion)

[image: Joint topology]

[image: Joint topology with finer subdivision]

Comment: For my model what should I exactly do I know I could add loop cuts but how many would I need and where would I place them?

Comment: Just look at the first reference image and create something similar. You can use Loop Cut (Ctrl R), or Extrude (E) the knee cap.

Comment: But if I used many loop cuts all around the leg, what if I rotated the leg and the legs very slightly becomes thin to the point where I am unable to determine if it actually got thinned out or not?

Comment: I really don't know what you mean by that. But if after you fix your topology you still have issues, it probably means there's either a problem with your vertex weights or a problem with your armature.

Comment: I added extra loop cuts and it does something different and weird. I just want it to rotate without it stretching weirdly.

Comment: Redo your vertex weighting.